# Using shared_ptr with sqlite3

Tags: c++, sqlite, shared-ptr

I am trying to use shared_ptr to protect the memory leaks that the sqlite3 library is throwing in my application.

I need to translate my plain c++ code to a protected version without doing a huge change. The current state of my code is something like:

```
sqlite3* db = NULL;
sqlite3_open(dbname.c_str(),   &db );
sqlite3_close( db );
```

And I have tried:

```
std::shared_ptr<sqlite3> db(NULL);
sqlite3_close( db.get() );
```

But I can not translate the open function because it is requesting a sqlite3** parameter that I am not able to emulate with a shared pointer.
I have found 
    std::shared_ptr connection(rawConnec, sqlite3_close);
but this kind of function have not official documentation or any of example.

I am so blocked, Thank you so much

Comment: "This kind of function" is a constructor, and [is documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Comment: Sorry @CL. , I didn't mean that it was not documented. I couldn't find it. Thank you for the link. Anyway, I don't understand what definition I should use if I can not use the shared_ptr definition as a variable because I should pass it as a double reference in the "open" function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::shared_ptr<sqlite3> db(nullptr);
{
  sqlite3* dbPtr = NULL;
  sqlite3_open(dbname.c_str(),   &dbPtr );
  db.reset(dpPtr, sqlite3_close);
}
```

Then once `db`  and all other `std::shared_ptr`s go out of scope `sqlite3_close` will be called on your resource.

However this is a bit of a hack and in the long run you will be much better off with a standard RAII class as is standard C++ practice.

Comment: Thanks @sjdowling, I have tested your work-around and it works fine. However, I could not remove all the memory leaks in my application but I think it could depend of the architecture or other parts of code.
Thanks a lot